# Get unique ID before saving the meeting in Outlook that must be same after saving the meeting

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on Outlook add-in, In which we are providing the service for ordering the catering products during the meeting scheduling.
I want to send the order along with the meeting (for which meeting i ordered the products) so in this case i need any id i.e MeetingId So can save this meetingId and order detail in the database.
When i will open scheduled  meeting from my Outlook calendar and on the behalf of that meetingId i  can get the order detail from the server and i can update the order.

So i'm looking any solution, Please share your suggestion here how  can i update my order inside the Add-ins from already scheduled meeting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the compose form you may call the `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync` method and then get the `itemId` property value. There is no need to call the `saveAsync` method if the appointment was saved previously.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But Problem is that i am ordering the products in appointment surface screen and at that time i need meetingId/ itemID for saving the order over the meeting in database.
So i can get the order for the particular meeting  from the database which i ordered.

Comment: Can confirm Eugene's answer. From compose meeting, you will need to call the `saveAsync` method and then get the `itemID` to save it in your database, we cannot get the itemID in compose before saving the meeting